# Nhibernate DetachedCriteria Left Outer Join on subquery

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, subquery, detachedcriteria

I'll only try to present the main part of the problem, because the whole situation is much more complicated - I am unable to achieve the following with DetachedCriteria

```
SELECT *
FROM User
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupItem
ON User.ID = GroupItem.UserID
AND _groupItemRestrictions_
```

There can be multiple GroupDefinitions, User can belong to multiple GroupItems which each belong to it's own GroupDefinition. Due to some complicated reason with paging/sorting and (multilevel) group behavior, I cannot achieve appropriate paging behavior with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupItem
ON User.ID = GroupItem.UserID
WHERE _groupItemRestrictions_
```

A query similar to the second one is produced this way:

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<User>()
...
GroupItem groupItem = null;
criteria.CreateAlias(() => groupItemAlias, () => groupItem,
                                                JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Or(...));
...
```

Is it possible to create the first query with DetachedCriteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Seems that there is no way to specify such a query with DetachedCriteria yet, but there is with HQL using a 'with' clause:</strike>

http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/05/nhibernate-210-hql-with-clause.html

http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg08451.html

UPDATE:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1946

The feature has been implemented now. Thanks to NH team :)